# UIPopoverController Delegate Problem?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I have a UIPopover that I want to use either

```
-(BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController{
    return NO;
}
```

or

```
-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController{}
```

on. Neither of them seem to work (and I'm sure once one is fixed, the other will be too since it's probably a problem with delegates). For delegates, here is what I have:

In optionsViewController.h, the view which is inside the popover:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol OptionsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>


-(void)didPick:(NSString *)string;
@end
id delegate;


@interface OptionsViewController : UIViewController <OptionsViewControllerDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
    NSMutableArray *list;

}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *passthroughViews;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *list;
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<OptionsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

and in the .m:

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

and in the .h of the view where the popover appears:

```
@interface exampleViewController : UIViewController <OptionsViewControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate>{
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
    OptionsViewController *optionsViewController;
}
```

and in the .m:

```
@synthesize popoverController;
@synthesize optionsViewController;
-(BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController{
    return NO;
}

    [popoverController release];
    [optionsViewController release];
```

In the ViewDidLoad, I have:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        optionsViewController =[[OptionsViewController alloc]init];
        optionsViewController.delegate = self;
        popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:optionsViewController];
        popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 216);
    }
```

To present the popover, I use:

```
-(IBAction)showDecadePopover{
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(150, 50, 150, 50) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
}
```

I'm probably missing something really obvious (that's why I gave so much of my code). Thanks so much!

Luke

Comment: Can you post the code for when you init and/or present the popover?

Comment: I added it to the question. Hope that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, simple fix. After you init the popoverController you need to set the exampleViewController as the delegate of it.

```
 [popoverController setDelegate:self];
```

PS: What is the `id delegate;` floating after your OptionsViewControllerDelegate protocol definition for?  Synthesizing `delegate`, which you already do, is all you need to create storage for it.